# How to remove commas from only few elements in a list

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension, slice

I have list:

```
['My name is Tom,', 'Im living in NY,', 'I have two brothers']
```

How can I remove commas inside of first two elements? I want to mention, that length of list could be bigger. I used:

```
list = [x[:-1] for x in list]
```

but it removed all lasts characters in string, not only in first two elements.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to remove all commas, or just the comma at the end? Maybe you should fix how you create the list in the first place. If you're read a CSV file, the commas should be specified as the separators.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.strip()` in a list comprehension for this:

```
>>> l = ['My name is Tom,', 'Im living in NY,', 'I have two brothers']
>>> [s.strip(',') for s in l]
['My name is Tom', 'Im living in NY', 'I have two brothers']
```

Alternatively, if strings within the list may have commas in the middle, str.replace() could be used:

```
>>> l = ['My name, is Tom,', 'Im living, in NY,', 'I have, two brothers']
>>> [s.replace(',', '') for s in l]
['My name is Tom', 'Im living in NY', 'I have two brothers']
```

Note that `list` should not be used as a variable name as it shadows the builtin `list` type.

Answer (score 1):

Use `x.rstrip(',')`.

Also don't name your variable `list`.